# Node/Javascript only send changed values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a simple application where I send values to a `mqtt broker` given by a `pot-meter` (variable resistor). The thing I am trying to accomplish is that I only send changed values to save bandwidth. I am trying `Object.observe`, but that does not do anything. Can anybody help me?

My code:

```
var analogValue = 0;

every((0.5).second(), function() {
    analogValue = my.sensor.analogRead();
    var values = {values:[{key:'resistance', value: analogValue}]}

    //another experiment here
    var arr = ['resitance', analogValue];
    Array.observe(arr, function(changes) {
      console.log(changes);
    });
    arr[1] = analogValue

    console.log('sent ',values,'to ',thingTopic)
    client.publish(thingTopic,  JSON.stringify(values));
});

var o = [analogValue];
Object.observe(o, function (changes) {
  console.log(changes);
  //eventually publish only changes to broker here
})
o.name = [analogValue]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `Object.observe`. You can just save the last measurement and check the new one against it. Like this:

```
// I'm assuming that any actual measurement will be different than 0
var lastMeasurement = 0;

every((0.5).second(), function() {
    var analogValue = my.sensor.analogRead();
    if (lastMeasurement !== analogValue) {
        // the new value is different
        var values = {values:[{key:'resistance', value: analogValue}]};
        client.publish(thingTopic,  JSON.stringify(values));

        // update the last measurement value
        lastMeasurement = analogValue;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll test it out :-) let you know if it works